# Saving multiple image from UIImagepickercontroller to sqlite3 db

Tags: ios, sqlite, uiimagepickercontroller

Can anyone briefly explain me how to save multiple image from UIImagepickercontroller to sqlite3 db

Comment: better u can save them in a folder in the app directory and save the path to that file in the database, while retrieving use the path which is stored in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the image data to base 64 for optimization and then save it in sqlite3 db. But it is not advisable to add image data into the sqlite.